# Installing RStan using Rocker

Tags: r, docker, wsl-2

I would like to be able to install the rstan package from binaries (without compiling from source).  This [blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2019/06/09/#022_rocker_and_ppas) by Dirk Eddelbuettel has some clear instructions that should enable me to do exactly that.  However I get the following error message when I try and install RStan.  Here are the commands I used.

```
docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-ubuntu:18.04 bash
apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade -y
apt-get install -y r-cran-rstan
```

This produces the following error message.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rstan : Depends: r-cran-v8 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Installing the R tidyverse package using Dirk's instructions works fine.  I am working on a Ubuntu OS within the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These things can happen -- the best best is to then try

```
sudo apt install r-cran-v8
```

which reveals `r-cran-node64` is required but not available.

I work much more with 20.04 than 18.04 so I don't what is going on here. I would recommend asking on the r-sig-debian list if anybody else has seen this.

PS And if you try 20.04 instead it works there.

Comment: Thanks.  It does work with Ubuntu 20.04.   I think your original blog post / lightning talk on rocker (Using Rocker and PPAs for Fun and Profit) is great.  Perhaps worth updating so that people use Ubuntu 20.04 by default?

Comment: Good to know it helps.  As for blog updates, that happens more naturally with the writing of newer updated posts.  Also, install glitches like the one you are seeing here with 18.04 tend to be temporary so it is impractical to update all blogs all the time.  Best to fix the issue...